# Measuring probabilities of 0 or 1 in a two qubit state

Tags: quantum-gate, textbook-and-exercises

I'm preparing for my upcoming exam, I need to determine the probabilities with which Bob measures 0 or 1 and in both cases describe the state of Alice, this is my state:

$$
|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \bigg[(1-i) \left \rvert 01 \right \rangle + \sqrt 3 i \left \rvert 11 \right \rangle\bigg]
$$

I guess I need to check the second qubit, which is always 1, and so we will always measure 1, not 0, but how to solve this mathematically?

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! Please add more details as to what approach you have tried, what is your understanding about measurements and where you are stuck exactly. Adding this will help people answer your question better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your state is separable. It can be written as

$$
|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt 5} \bigg[(1-i) \left \rvert 0 \right \rangle + \sqrt 3 i \left \rvert 1 \right \rangle\bigg]\otimes \rvert 1\rangle.
$$

Your measurement operators when Bob measures in the computational basis are $\{ I \otimes \rvert 0\rangle\langle 0\rvert, I \otimes \rvert 1\rangle\langle 1\rvert \}$. You see that Bob obtains the outcome $\rvert 1 \rangle$ with probability 1.